# Shared Session Manager object in analytics always giving Contact value null

Tags: xdb, xconnect, experience-analytics

I am fetching contact on the basis of "SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE". When I am creating Shared session manager client object and trying to fetch contact it's giving me null value every time.

**Scenario:** On the same browser, Contact abc@gmail.com entered his details and I have saved it into XDB and created a new contact. After some time another contact xyz@gmail.com entered his details and saved it into XDB (New Contact Created with email identifier).

I need to populate the latest entered contact data in MVC forms like Name, Mobile, Email, etc.

So I am trying to get the latest details using the ssharedSessionManager object using below code:

```
ContactKeyCookie contactCookie = new ContactKeyCookie();
            if (!contactCookie.IsNewContact)
            {
                Guid contactId = contactCookie.ContactId;
                var contactManager = Factory.CreateObject("tracking/contactManager", true) as ContactManager;
                var contact = contactManager.LoadContact(contactId);
                var sharedSessionManager = (SharedSessionStateManager)Factory.CreateObject("tracking/sharedSessionState/manager", true);
                // Try to load the contact from the Shared Session.
                Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.Contact sessionContact = sharedSessionManager.LockAndLoadContact(contactId);
}
```

sessionContact always giving me null value instead of giving me latest entry i.e. xyz@gmail.com. 
Thanks.